# How to generate the call graph of a binary file?

Tags: binary-analysis, elf, call-graph

I have a non-stripped ELF binary for which I want to create a call graph as a [dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)) file. Is there such a tool which generates the call graph?

EDIT: Is there away in addition to the conventional call graph to find a call graph between libraries based on the executable. For example showing the call graph only of from `libc` to `pthread`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [radare2](https://github.com/radare/radare2) or one of the alternatives below to generate a full call-graph in dot format.

### radare2 Installation

First of all, install radare2 from git repository:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/radare/radare2.git
$ cd radare2
$ ./sys/install.sh
```

### Analysis

After you've downloaded and installed radare2, open your binary and perform analysis on it using the `aaa` command:

```
$ r2 /bin/ls
[0x004049a0]> aaa
[x] Analyze all flags starting with sym. and entry0 (aa)
[x] Analyze function calls (aac)
[x] Analyze len bytes of instructions for references (aar)
[x] Constructing a function name for fcn.* and sym.func.* functions (aan)
[x] Type matching analysis for all functions (afta)
[x] Use -AA or aaaa to perform additional experimental analysis.
```

### Output visual graph

The `ag` command and subcommands can help you to output the visual graph into [Graphviz](http://www.webgraphviz.com/) format.

```
[0x00000000]> ag?
Usage: ag<graphtype><format> [addr]
Graph commands:
| aga[format]             Data references graph
| agA[format]             Global data references graph
| agc[format]             Function callgraph
| agC[format]             Global callgraph
| agd[format] [fcn addr]  Diff graph
| agf[format]             Basic blocks function graph
| agi[format]             Imports graph
| agr[format]             References graph
| agR[format]             Global references graph
| agx[format]             Cross references graph
| agg[format]             Custom graph
| ag-                     Clear the custom graph
| agn[?] title body       Add a node to the custom graph
| age[?] title1 title2    Add an edge to the custom graph

Output formats:
| <blank>                 Ascii art
| *                       r2 commands
| d                       Graphviz dot
... <truncated> ...
| w [path]                Write to path or display graph image (see graph.gv.format and graph.web)
```

You're searching for the `agCd` command. The `C` specifies to output a full ("global") call-graph of the program. The `d` specifies to output in Graphviz dot format.

```
[0x004049a0]> agCd > output.dot
```

The `dot` utility is part of the Graphviz software which can be installed using `sudo apt-get install graphviz`.
You can view your output in any offline [*dot* viewer](http://www.graphviz.org/content/resources), paste the output into an [online Graphviz viewer](http://www.webgraphviz.com/) and even convert the *dot* file to PNG:

```
$ r2 /bin/ls
[0x004049a0]> aa
[x] Analyze all flags starting with sym. and entry0 (aa)
[0x004049a0]> agCd > output.dot
[0x004049a0]> !!dot -Tpng -o callgraph.png output.dot
```

To read more about radare2 it is recommended to read [radare2 book](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book).

---

### Alternatives

- **[gen-callgraph](https://github.com/onlyuser/gen-callgraph)** - gen-callgraph is a script to generate call graph from elf binary
- **[IDA Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/)** - generate GDL (Graph Description File) call graph using CTRL+F12, save it and then convert it to *dot* file with one of the following options:

  - [graph-easy](http://search.cpan.org/~tels/Graph-Easy/bin/graph-easy) - Convert between graph formats
  - This [perl script](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/IDA_Pro#Converting_gdl_flow_graphs_to_dot_files) from Multimedia Wiki

*The [free version](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml) of IDA is also capable of generate GDL of call graph but it is only available as exe, use wine on Linux to run it*

Comment: Is there away to get a call graph between libraries or files rather call graph between functions?

Comment: You can use `il` to get libraries used by the binary or `rabin2 -l /bin/ls` which is the same

Comment: I don't know of a command to generate a call graph of only libraries, sorry

Answer (score 8):

You might want to give [angr](http://angr.io) a try.

- Load the binary. Suppose `p` is the angr Project instance.
- Generate a CFG: `cfg = p.analyses.CFG(show_progressbar=True)`.
- Access/traverse the call graph (which is a networkx.DiGraph) in whatever way you want: `cfg.functions.callgraph`.

> For example showing the call graph only of specific address range or specific static library

You can limit the range of CFG generation by passing the `regions` argument to `CFG()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use angr-utils in order to generate the graph from angr : https://github.com/axt/angr-utils

For more information please see:

https://github.com/axt/angr-utils/blob/master/examples/plot_cg/README.md

[image]

Comment: You should elaborate a bit...

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) or [KCachegrind](https://kcachegrind.github.io/html/Home.html). Much simpler than any other alternative.

Comment: but are these static analyzers? or only report what is called in some typical run?

Comment: Callgrind is based on Valgrind, a serializing dynamic analysis framework.