# What tool is able to analyze/decompile asm execution trace?

Tags: decompile, x64dbg, assembly

I got a trace of the execution from `x64dbg` and I need to analyze it. The problem is that the trace is quite large and there are quite big chunks of the code that repeat (I assume they are loops).
I would like to have some kind of tool that would be able to produce a graph or perform simple analyze/decompile to group loops into separate blocks and to simplify the flow.

Is there a tool like this or all of this should be done manually?

Comment: If you're talking about Control Flow Graph, check out this question: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16081/how-to-generate-the-call-graph-of-a-binary

Comment: I'm looking for a static analysis tool that's able to analyze logs and not executable. Meanwhile, I had some success of finding duplicate parts with `CPD` from `PMD`.